# Another riddle - what am I?

Tags: riddle

> My S__t helps me _av__ate
>
> I am smarter than  _o_s
>
> I don't usually _wea_
>
> I communicate in over 15 vocalisations

What am I?

**Hints:**

Word 1:

> Nasal

Word 2:

> Get around

Word 3:

> An animal

Word 4:

> When you exercise

Comment: Just to confirm, _"_wea_t"_ has two missing letters, right?

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed Ah sorry, Edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>I guess it's a</s>

> bat

The sentence is

> My **snout** helps me **navigate** I am smarter than **dogs** I don't usually **sweat** I communicate in over 15 vocalisations

**Second attempt**

> Is it a pig? Read this on an article: 
>  "Here's the dirt on pigs: They are perhaps the smartest, cleanest domestic animals known - more so than cats and dogs, according to some experts. But pigs don't have sweat glands, so they roll around in the mud to stay cool. A sign of their cleverness came from experiments in the 1990s. Pigs were trained to move a cursor on a video screen with their snouts and used the cursor to distinguish between scribbles they knew and those they were seeing for the first time. They learned the task as quickly as chimpanzees." 
> (source: http://www.nbcnews.com/id/24628983/ns/technology_and_science-science/t/smartest-animals/#.XCOxVVz7QdU)

Comment: Nice try, one gap is wrong and it’s not a bat